# Are CuddleFix participants engaged in prostitution?

Tags: criminal-law, definition, prostitution

Is CuddleFix (http://www.cuddlefix.com) prostitution, or not? If not, where (or at what actions) is the line drawn exactly?

In brief: you pay them to come to your house and lie in bed with you and spoon. With clothes on. No kissing.

Regarding jurisdiction – let's say Alabama, then the U.S. at large, and finally "the West" generally.

Answer (score 1):

See http://codes.lp.findlaw.com/alcode/13A/12/3/2.

Is the cuddling or spooning a sexual act or sexual contact?  A court would have to decide.  Perhaps there is some binding precedent on the books; I do not know.

The answer to this question could be different for different jurisdictions in Alabama, since local ordinances might exist.  It will almost certainly be different for different states in the US, let alone "the west" generally, whatever that means.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think there'd be any precedent for what constitutes "sexual contact"? I could think of a few definitions - some would be what CuddleFix is doing and some wouldn't. Have any courts already weighed in?

Comment: @Patrick87 Sure there is probably precedent, but precedent depends very much on jurisdiction.  I do not know for certain, however.  Perhaps someone who does will weigh in.

Comment: Thanks to whomever for the down vote. Would you care to offer any suggestion to improve the answer, or an answer of your own?